# Integrate $4x/(x^4-1)$ dx

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble solving the integral

$$\int_{5/4}^{13/12}\frac{4x}{x^4-1}\,dx$$

I have a feeling it is to do with the log integration identity but can't seem to manipulate it without involving complex numbers, something outside of this module (so I should be able to solve without them).

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:*

As $x^4 - 1 = (x^2 - 1)(x^2 + 1)$, let's try

$$\frac{4x}{x^4 - 1} = \frac{2x}{x^2 - 1} - \frac{2x}{x^2 + 1}$$

Now, those look integrable, following the pattern $\int \frac {f'}{f}$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{4x}{x^4-1}=\frac{1}{(x-1)}+\frac{1}{(x+1)}-\frac{2 x}{(x^2+1)}$$

Comment: And let the cancellation commence...

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{4x}{x^4-1}dx$$
Partial Fraction Decomposition on $\frac{4x}{x^4-1} = \frac{4x}{(x^2+1)(x^2-1)}$ gives $\frac{a}{x^2+1} + \frac{b}{x^2-1} = 4x \implies a(x^2-1)+b(x^2+1) = 4x$. Solving this gives $a=-2x, b=2x$
$$=\int\frac{2x}{x^2-1}-\int\frac{2 x}{x^2+1}dx$$
$$=\log|x^2-1| -\log(x^2+1) + C$$

Comment: You need absolute value signs on the argument of the first logarithm.  Otherwise +1

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{4x}{x^4 - 1} dx &=& \int \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{2x}{x^2+1} dx\\
&=& \log|x-1| + \log|x+1| -\log|x^2+1| + C
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int \frac{4x\ dx}{x^4-1} \text{ substitute } u = x^2, du = 2xdx \\
= \int \frac{2du}{u^2-1}
= \log|1-u| - \log(u+1) + C
$$

Comment: You need absolute value signs on the argument of the first logarithm.  Otherwise +1

Comment: @gt6989b No problem, +1

Comment: @Dr.MV fixed, thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.